# Once an element has been clipped how to you un-clipp it

Tags: html, clipping

I am working on a web page for a class and we have to clip an image so that only a small box appears but when we hover over it it has to return to full size.

```
    .marker p{
        background-color: rgb(70,76,222);
        width: 150px; 
        height: 170px;
        color: white; 
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 15px;
        overflow: visible;
        z-index:1;
        clip: rect(0px,20px,20px,0px);
    }
    .marker p:hover{


    }
```

the original dimensions are 150 x 170, then it is clipped to 0,20,20,0 how to i return it to its full dimensions when mouse hovers over the 20x20 rectangle

Answer (score 0):

```
.marker p:hover{
    width:140px;
    height:170px;
}
```